# ffmpeg reducing the qualitu of photos

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert photos to video and i am pretty successfull so far.
However I am facing quality issue.

```
    $command1="ffmpeg -r 1/1 -pattern_type glob -i 'pics/*.jpg' -vf \"pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2\" finalPics/video.mp4";
    exec($command1);
```

What is wrong with the command as video quality is really reducing the quality of images

Comment: This is a php or ffmpeg question?

Comment: ffmpeg calling from php

Comment: You better add ffmpeg tag as php seems is irrelevant here

Comment: added the tag ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

ffmpeg -r 1/1 -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i 'pics/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p pics/video.mp4

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you've changed and why it should solve OP's problem.

Comment: No need for `-profile:v high`. This encoder will automatically choose the profile. Recommend adding `-movflags +faststart` output option as I'm guessing the output will be viewed via progressive download.